# Issues with clicking a link using partial link text

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to click on an address in a table using partial link text, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I will only be able to use partial due to formatting issues between the spreadsheet I'm getting these addresses from and how the website has them formatted slightly differently. The location of the address in the table changes on each account so I cannot use a normal xpath. Additionally there are versions of the address in this table that are not able to be clicked. I know I am in the correct frame, using the exact xpath allows me to click on the address with no problem. I am not able to share the website due to confidentiality reasons.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
Address = '1600 Blah Blah Rd, 10009, New York City, NY, United States'

Street_Number = Address.split()[0]

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(Street_Number):
```

This gives a no such element exception.

```py
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + Street_Number + "')]"):
    try:
        element.click()
    except:
        pass
```

This DOES work, but the problem is for some reason if it is not in a `for` loop it will somehow successfully click on the versions of the address that are not link text and will end the program there having not clicked the address that is actually a link. It doesn't throw an exception when clicking something that isn't clickable, and I don't know how that is possible. It also doesn't do anything when it allegedly 'clicks' on these non-links so I'm not sure what it thinks it is clicking. Once it does click the correct link it will throw an exception because it is in a new window.

This wouldn't be a big deal, except I need it to logout and go the next account if there are no clickable versions of that address. The exception that I would use for that case is being taken up by the `pass`. I really need the partial link text to work because I haven't figured out how to nest all the `try` and `if` statements together to correctly do this.

Any ideas of how to make partial link text work in this case?

Comment: Does the clickable address link contains 'a' anchor tags? if so, you can use that on your xpath like these - xpath("//a[contains(text(), '" + Street_Number + "').  This will filter only clickable links.

Comment: They unfortunately do not have anchor tags.